# opencv (C language) video writer can't use methods

Tags: c, opencv

Here is the program (part of it):

```
CvVideoWriter* vidWriterDepth = 0;
```

in while loop (getting video frames from camera):

```
if (vidWriterColored == 0) {
   vidWriterDepth = cvCreateVideoWriter("depth_vid", CV_FOURCC('Z', 'L', 'I', 'B'), 30 , cvSize(rawImg1->width, rawImg1->height), 0);
}
...
vidWriterDepth->
```

Here I'm trying to call the methods of vidWriterDepth but getting an error:
`Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed` (showing the vidWriterDepth->).
So I can't use any methods of     vidWriterDepth. 
Without it it compiles even with creating and initializing the     vidWriterDepth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder, are there methods in C?

You have to use functions like

```
cvWriteFrame(vidWriterDepth, FImage);
```

It is called C-interface. Arbitrary example from [online help](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-grab). Look at `C:` description

```
VideoCapture::grab

Grabs the next frame from video file or capturing device.
C++: bool VideoCapture::grab()
Python: cv2.VideoCapture.grab() → retval
C: int cvGrabFrame(CvCapture* capture)
Python: cv.GrabFrame(capture) → int
```

Comment: I dont want to grab frame. I want to write IplImage to the video in C. Btw yeah its C they dont have methods there.. Let me try

Comment: Its working but not creating the file (called the cvReleaseVideoWriter at the end). Any ideas?

Comment: check that codec ZLIB is available (I don't know this name), cvCreateVideoWriter returns not null and so on. Is file created with small size or nothing happens?

Comment: already fixed. there is something wrong with setting loseless CV_FOURCC. Tried different combinations and got it working but not in loseless format.

Comment: "I wonder, are there methods in C?" AFAIK methods were functions in classes... but maybe let's not get too hung up on it ;)